# Search dir and subdirs

Tags: python

I am attempting to make this function (that searches a dir for a given string) search all sub dirs as well, and do this recursively. I don't know Python well enough to begin. Any guidance would be great.

Thanks!

```
def grep(regex, base_dir):
    matches = list()
    for filename in os.listdir(base_dir):
        full_filename = os.path.join(base_dir, filename)
        if not os.path.isfile(full_filename):
            continue
        with open(os.path.join(base_dir, filename)) as fh:
            content = fh.read()
            matches = matches + re.findall(regex, content)
    return matches
```

Comment: I think you're looking for os.walk(path)

Comment: Maybe something like 
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        print os.path.join(root, name)
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to crawl an entire directory, try `os.walk()`. Something like this may work (untested, but can adjust if it doesn't work):

```
def grep(regex, base_dir):
    matches = list()
    # os.walk() returns a tuple - the directory path, a list of directories and the files
    for dirpath, dirname, files in os.walk(base_dir):
        # Iterate through the directory list, reading the files
        for directory in dirname:
          for filename in os.listdir(directory):
              with open(os.path.join(base_dir, directory, filename)) as fh:
                  content = fh.read()
                  matches = matches + re.findall(regex, content)
    return matches
```

Comment: I like this...looks like i get a:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ditto.py", line 46, in <module>
    moduleString  = grep('require\\(\\s*\\[[^]]*\\]\\s*\\)', ".")
  File "ditto.py", line 9, in grep
    with open(os.path.join(dirpath, directory, filename)) as fh:
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 68, in join
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Comment: @user1738992 Try it now - apparently I have no ability to write without testing :)

Comment: That error is resolved, but now I get an error when I encounter a directory: ```IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: './tests/testFolder'``` Thanks for the help btw!

Comment: @user1738992 No prob! Actually in a meeting now but will jump on as soon as I get back :)

Answer (score 1):

For recursive traversal try `os.walk`. You can find out how to use it here: www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/03/python-oswalk-example/

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this:

```
def find_file_matches(filename, regex):
    with open(filename, 'rt') as fh:
        return re.findall(regex, fh.read())

def walktree(top):
    """ Walk the directory tree starting from top, and
        yield a tuple of each folder and all the files in it. """
    names = os.listdir(top)
    yield top, (name for name in names if not os.path.isdir(name))
    for name in names:
        if os.path.isdir(name):
            for (newtop, children) in walktree(os.path.join(top, name)):
                yield newtop, children

def grep(regex, base_dir="."):
    matches = []
    for dir, files in walktree(base_dir):
        for file in files:
            filename = os.path.join(dir, file)
            matches.append(find_file_matches(filename, regex))
    return matches
```

Answer (score -1):

from the command line

```
find . -type d | grep -i nameofdir
```

or something similar.

Comment: That's not Python. And why assume he's on a linux machine?

Comment: sometimes what a program is written is made redundant by something simple on the command line. This will work on a Windows machine with MSysGit or just Ming. It should also work on a Mac CLI.